# Emacs shortcut to kill other visible windows

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

In Emacs, we can [make 2 or more windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Split-Window.html) in a buffer.

I am just wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to close all the other windows that don't have the current focus. Ie, when there are only 2 windows and the focus in on the one above, how to quickly close the one below?

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is defined in `window.el`: `(define-key ctl-x-map "1" 'delete-other-windows)` and you can of course create different shortcuts -- I bind `delete-window` and `delete-other-windows` to my favorite shortcuts and use them all the time.  I also have `delete-window-left/right/up/down` available, but don't really use them:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14352/2287

Comment: @lawlist - Please just post that as an answer: `C-x 1`, so the OP can accept it and the question gets removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut `C-x 1` for the function `delete-other-windows` is defined in `window.el` -- i.e., `(define-key ctl-x-map "1" 'delete-other-windows)`.  See the section of the manual for deleting and rearranging windows:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Change-Window.html